# How can iPadian do this?

Tags: windows-10, ipad, simulation

I am using [iPadian](http://www.ipadian.net/) on my Windows 10 pc, and today after opening the browser in it I saw two prompts:

[image: p1]

and

[image: p2]

(The prompts at the bottom of the screen which tells to install google app and chrome on "iPad")

But shouldn't these prompts appear in a browser running on iPad? Or is iPadian anyway masking the identity of the device and showing it as an iPad to the servers?

**Note**

iPadian is created by Adobe AIR, and is a third-party software so it can in no way have the real safari browser, the browser shown here is not safari, but a simulation of it.

Comment: Can anyone with 300+ rep add the tag iPadian? It would be helpful.

Comment: @Ramhound The browser app icon is that of safari, and it's design too. But the real thing is different. The bar you see at the top, with buttons in it, none of them are functional except the address bar.

Comment: @Ramhound moreover iPadian is created by Adobe AIR, and is a third-party software so it can in no way have the real safari browser.

Comment: Alright, it still comes down to the browser agent.  A tag still for wouldn’t be appropriate in this case not is asking for one in your question (take that request to meta.SU)

Comment: @Ramhound ok leave the tag, I just want to know the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> iPadian is created by Adobe AIR, and is a third-party software so it can in no way have the real safari browser, the browser shown here is not safari, but a simulation of it.  But shouldn't these prompts appear in a browser running on iPad?

There is one of two things happening:

- Either the browser agent is set to that of the browser agent of an iPad iOS device which means Google would make the suggestion themselves.
- The other possibility is that the simulator itself is adding that frame to the page since that’s what would happen on I real iOS device.

Comment: Since iPadian is an Adobe AIR program it likely will not be possible to actually determine what is happening.  Since the documentation on the program I did find wasn’t very detailed. *Paid software makes it impossible for me to investigate further myself.*

Comment: Could you please explain the browser agent part in some detail. Your second point can also be the case.

Comment: There isn’t anything else to say.